# Java java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I try access info(String var) method in a final class that has a non visible contstructor Class(String var0, Logger var1, LoggerContext var2)

```java
try {
Constructor<? extends Logger> var0 = logger.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Logger.class, LoggerContext.class);

var0.setAccessible(true);

logger.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("info", String.class).invoke(var0.newInstance(), new String(message));

} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Note: new String(message) - this is completely not needed

Comment: The question is: what you are trying to actually do, this looks like you are trying to do something else, that's not how you are supposed to use any kind of logger.

Comment: I am trying to access a method from logback, specificly Logger#info(String)

Comment: Then you should get instance of logger from logger manager/factory, like `LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger").info("message")` where name of logger is often name of class but it does not need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `var0.newInstance()` with the args of it.

Just pass objects of the `String`, `Logger` and `LoggerContext` to the `newInstance()` method.

Comment: Then I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

logger.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("info", String.class).invoke(var0, new String(message));

Comment: `var0.newInstance(String.class, Logger.class, LoggerContext.class)` @dan1st
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: You have to call it with **objects of the type** of these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! *Then you should get instance of logger from logger manager/factory, like LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger").info("message") where name of logger is often name of class but it does not need to be. - @GotoFinal*

EDIT: Sorry I don't know how to mark the right answer, quite new here.

Comment: and for future: xyproblem.info, please always include what you are trying to do, not just how.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, will always include it in future questions ;)